# @tailrec error in scala eclipse worksheet: expected start of definition

Tags: scala

i'm new to scala and i'm currently practicing in the worksheet.
I noticed that @tailrec doesn't work in the worksheet even though i added the import

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
```

This is the version of scala i'm using

```
Scala code runner version 2.10.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

Is there a way to get it to work?
Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the code that is producing the error, it is impossible to determine what is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue you described is a bug in the Eclipse IDE for Scala:
https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1001636#/activity/ticket

> The workaround is to put the @tailrec in a def or a different object.

e.g.:

```
package tailrecfunc

import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Session17 {
  val block = {
    @tailrec
    def tailrecfunc(n: Int): Int =
     if(n == 0) n; else tailrecfunc(n - 1)

    tailrecfunc(4)
  }                                          
}
```

This way the scala interpreter will warn you when the function is not tail recursive

Answer (score 4):

Be careful that you are not mistaking how the `@tailrec` annotation works - it does not force a function to be optimised by the compiler in a "tail-recursive manner" (the compiler will alwasys make that optimisation anyway, if it can).

Rather it is simply a marker that you can use to tell the compiler "I think this function has been successfully written in a tail-recursive manner, please tell me if you cannot optimise it that way."

That is, use it where you want to be sure that you have correctly written a function intended to be tail-recusive, and the compiler can point out when you get it wrong.

Does that make sense of what you are seeing? I can't say anything more useful without seeing example code where you have used the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

First define and stub the function you want to annotate, then go back and add the annotation.